# Apache SERVER variable set up SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have fresh installed WHM/cPanel and my scripts requires SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY variable, which is not on my current $_SERVER variable list. How can I have this variable set in the CGI script's environment?

Answer (score 1):

This is a CGI variable which apache (or nginx or whatever https server) will set when a client connects with a client SSL certificate.

For it to be set ever, the web server needs to request and accept client certificates.  In apache, you can do this by adding the `SSLVerifyClient` directive to your configuration (do this in the virtual host configuration for the vhost which will be running your script).  This variable should be set as long as `SSLVerifyClient` is set to something other than `none`, but its contents are not terribly useful unless it is `optional_no_ca` or `optional` (as `require` implies that the certificate is valid if the connection was allowed).

You may also want to specify a CA certificate against which certificates are to be validated (this is the CA certificate which will act as a trust root for your client certificates, and probably directly sign them).  For this, specify the `SSLCACertificateFile` or `SSLCACertificatePath` directive.

Keep in mind that after changing this configuration you will have to reload your apache configuration.

To test, browse to the site with a browser containing a client certificate, and try presenting the certificate or not.  In both cases, the variable should be set.  However, if you are not asked for a client certificate, the variable will be unset and you can also infer that the configuration directive didn't take effect (double-check your configuration; the directive should be in the same scope as `SSLEngine On` and can only be usefully specified where `SSLEngine On` is set).

Comment: `SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca` is enough for me, but if I put this directive in configuration it does not work cause `$_SERVER` does not contain `SSL_CLINET_VERIFY` line which by default (with no directive) shows `NULL`.

Comment: `SSL_CLINET_VERIFY` has a typo.  In any case, see my edit.

Comment: Well, directive `SSLOptions StdEnvVars` shows additional variables including SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY, but I found something strange after: Safari accepts client certificate as but FF and Chrome shows `NONE`.

Comment: Not accepts, but provides.  Client certificates are presented to the server by the browser.  You have to make sure of course that the client certificate is installed and available to each browser you use - firefox specifically uses a separate store from everything else.

Comment: Client certificates are installed correctly. I am sure this is a server-side issue. May Firefox and Chrome act like this cause they don't trust server? After inspecting `$_SERVER` variable onall browsers I found different `SSL_CIPHER` values. Safari has `AES128-SHA`, Firefox & Chrome has `DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA`. This lets me think, that Safari is more trusting than FF. Is it? If so, i need set up server so it is more trusted.